# How to use cts:values/cts:element-attribute-values with filtered condition

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have below two documents and range index is created on element "Id" ,"Name", "Key" and "Value" of data type string, string, string and integer respectively.

```
<Root Id='1'>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
 <Child>
  <Key>1</Key>
  <Value>10</Value>
 </Child>
 <Child>
  <Key>2</Key>
  <Value>20</Value>
 </Child>
</Root>

<Root Id='2'>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
 <Child>
  <Key>1</Key>
  <Value>20</Value>
 </Child>
 <Child>
  <Key>2</Key>
  <Value>10</Value>
 </Child>
</Root>
```

Below query should return document 1, but instead it return both documents because `cts:element-attribute-values` returns result based on "unfiltered".

```
cts:element-attribute-values(xs:QName("Root"),xs:QName("Id"), (), (),
cts:and-query((
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("Name"), "ABC"),
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("Child"),
        cts:and-query((
            cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("Key"), "1"),
            cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Value"), "<", 15)
        ))
    )
))
)
```

Is there a way by which I get result based on filtering.

Note: I do not want to use cts:search() as my query is going to return more than 100,000 records

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly best practice to have one document per "row", but you can also use positions to resolve this: if you have the two value queries in the same `cts:element-query` and you have word positions and range positions enabled, the indexes can use positions to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `cts:element-attribute-values` for the `$query` says:

> Only include values in fragments selected by the cts:query, and compute frequencies from this set of included values. The **values do not need to match the query**, but they **must occur in fragments selected by the query**. The fragments are not filtered to ensure they match the query, but instead selected in the same manner as "unfiltered" cts:search operations. If a string is entered, the string is treated as a cts:word-query of the specified string.

As you already noticed, your query filter does not work unfiltered, because it returns false-positives. `cts:element-attribute-values` also does not have a filtered option.

You could try to do the following:

Create a **fragment root** for `Child`. This allows your query to run unfiltered without returning false-positives.

```
cts:element-attribute-values(xs:QName("Root"),xs:QName("Id"), (), (),
  cts:and-query((
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("Name"), "ABC"),
      cts:document-fragment-query(
        cts:element-query(xs:QName("Child"),
          cts:and-query((
              cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("Key"), "1"),
              cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Value"), "<", 15)
          ))
       )
      )
    ))
)
```

Explanation on what i did here:

By creating a fragment root on `Child` each Child is saved in a own Fragment. This way the and-query on `Key` and `Value` does only return fragments, which really contain the given values. By creating a `document-fragment-query` you will check if a document contains one of the fragments (This is needed, because cross fragment search doesn't work).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using fragmentation to solve this. It unnecessarily slows down search because of extra joins, and it makes querying much less intuitive because of the fragment boundaries within the document. Enabling positions as suggested by Mary is much simpler and faster, or save each `Child` as a separate document with a copy of `Root`-level info as mentioned by Mary as well..